# Create an alert if the value increase > 5 - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alert

Code:

```
SELECT 
    product_name, model_year, list_price, COUNT(product_name) AS QUANTITY 
FROM
    [production].[products]
GROUP BY 
    model_year, list_price, product_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(product_name) > 1
ORDER BY 
    product_name DESC
```

I created this SP to make it easy

```
EXEC SP_CheckQuantity
```

I want to create a alert that runs every hour and then **IF** there is a value greater than 5 send me an email

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932372/how-to-send-an-e-mail-from-database-if-some-condition-is-met

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!